# setting a timer, pausing it on mouse over, then reset it again

Tags: jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Hi have a problem with the setInterval and clearInterval, here is my current code:

```
var myTimer = 0;    
var myTimer = setInterval(function() { fadedots(); }, 1000);

function fadedots(){

    $("ul li.dots").fadeTo('fast', 0.5, function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
    });
};
$('#map div').css('cursor','pointer').bind({
  mouseenter: function() {
//  $("#map div > div").hide();
    $(this).children().show();
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    myTimer = 0;
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $("#map div > div").hide();
    myTimer = setInterval(function() { fadedots(); }, 1000);
    myTimer = 0;

  }
});
```

It currently works, but when I mouseenter again on another point is doesn't run again?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Just out of interest, what happens if you change setInterval instances to: setInterval("fadedots();", 1000);

Comment: Afraid that didn't work... thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this?

```
myTimer = 0;
```

That doesn't make sense to me. Remove both of those. You don't have to clear the variable after clearing the interval, it's perfectly safe to `clearInterval()` a timer more than one.

Also are you sure you want to run a timer when you first get to the page?

Comment: Yes? - maybe... its for fadeTo dots located on a world map, onLoad fadesIn/out on mouseenter stops, shows tooltip, onclick colorbox to more information. mouseleave start/continue again until it hits a timeout?

Comment: He's right, try removing myTimer, it doesnt need to be set especially after the setInterval.